# Sequelize | Polymorphic association to the same table and eager loading

Tags: sql, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have the following models:

```
Comments.hasMany(Comments, { as: 'comments' });
Comments.belongsTo(Comments, { as: 'comment' });
Comments.hasMany(Likes, { as: 'likes' });
Likes.belongsTo(Comments, { as: 'comment' });
```

Both Comments and Likes are polymorphic, cause comments might be related to different models like Comments, Images, Videos and Likes might be related to different models as well. I've decided to make a polymorphic relation between Comments and Comments itself, cause users might comment other comments (as in Facebook). I have an issue with a findAll query to get all main Comments (where commentableId IS NULL) with their Comments including their likes (both for the parent and children comments). I've tried something like this:

```
    const comments = await this.commentModel.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'content', 'createdAt'],
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
      where: { commentableId: null },
      include: [
        {
          model: Likes,
        },
        {
          model: Comment,
          as: 'comments',
          include: [
            {
              model: Likes,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
```

But it doesn't return likes for nested comments, this is the generated SQL query:

```
select
    "Comment"."id",
    "Comment"."content",
    "Comment"."createdAt",
    "likes"."id" as "likes.id",
    "likes"."userId" as "likes.userId",
    "likes"."likeableId" as "likes.likeableId",
    "likes"."likeableType" as "likes.likeableType",
    "likes"."createdAt" as "likes.createdAt",
    "likes"."updatedAt" as "likes.updatedAt",
    "comments"."id" as "comments.id",
    "comments"."content" as "comments.content",
    "comments"."userId" as "comments.userId",
    "comments"."commentableId" as "comments.commentableId",
    "comments"."commentableType" as "comments.commentableType",
    "comments"."createdAt" as "comments.createdAt",
    "comments"."updatedAt" as "comments.updatedAt"
from
    "comments" as "Comment"
left outer join "likes" as "likes" on
    "Comment"."id" = "likes"."likeableId"
left outer join "comments" as "comments" on
    "Comment"."id" = "comments"."commentableId"
left outer join "likes" as "comments->likes" on
    "comments"."id" = "comments->likes"."likeableId"
where
    "Comment"."commentableId" is null
order by
    "Comment"."createdAt" desc
```

The nested relation between Comments and Likes is aliased as `comments->likes` in the JOIN, but it doesn't include this alias in the SELECT, just `likes`. Am I doing something wrong? Perhaps I shouldn't have used polymorphic association in this case and just a field like `parentCommentId` on the Comments model. However since I need polymorphic association there to connect the Comments to different models I wanted to reuse it also for a relation between Comments and Comments. Could you suggest something here? When a remove a include for the parent Comments:

```
    const comments = await this.commentModel.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'content', 'createdAt'],
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
      where: { commentableId: null },
      include: [
        // {
        //   model: Likes,
        // },
        {
          model: Comment,
          as: 'comments',
          include: [
            {
              model: Likes,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
```

It doesn't work at all, it throws an error: `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "likes"` and the generated SQL query:

```
select
    "Comment"."id",
    "Comment"."content",
    "Comment"."createdAt",
    "comments"."id" as "comments.id",
    "comments"."content" as "comments.content",
    "comments"."userId" as "comments.userId",
    "comments"."commentableId" as "comments.commentableId",
    "comments"."commentableType" as "comments.commentableType",
    "comments"."createdAt" as "comments.createdAt",
    "comments"."updatedAt" as "comments.updatedAt",
    "likes"."id" as "likes.id",
    "likes"."userId" as "likes.userId",
    "likes"."likeableId" as "likes.likeableId",
    "likes"."likeableType" as "likes.likeableType",
    "likes"."createdAt" as "likes.createdAt",
    "likes"."updatedAt" as "likes.updatedAt"
from
    "comments" as "Comment"
left outer join "comments" as "comments" on
    "Comment"."id" = "comments"."commentableId"
left outer join "likes" as "comments->likes" on
    "comments"."id" = "comments->likes"."likeableId"
where
    "Comment"."commentableId" is null
order by
    "Comment"."createdAt" desc;
```

So it looks like it uses a wrong alias in the SELECT (likes instead of comments->likes). Could it be a sequelize issue or I am doing something wrong?